# Laravel: PHPUnit tests not triggering

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel, laravel-4, phpunit

I want to test one of my classes, but it looks like the `Phpunit` is not working.
**This is the test below:**

```
<?php

use NERO\Datagrids\Datagrid;

class DatagridTest extends TestCase
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->datagrid = new Datagrid;
    }

    public function testStopMethod()
    {
        $response = $this->datagrid->stop();
        $this->assertEquals($response, 'Stop');
    }

}
```

**And the class itself:**

```
<?php

namespace NERO\Datagrids;

class Datagrid {

    public function stop()
    {
        return 'Stop';
    }

}
```

I don't event get any reponse from the command line. I do the following and nothing happens..

```
intelis:laravel me$ clear
intelis:laravel me$ vendor/bin/phpunit 
intelis:laravel me$
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please not use `__construct`, instead:

```
<?php

use NERO\Datagrids\Datagrid;

class DatagridTest extends TestCase
{
    protected $datagrid;

    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->datagrid = new Datagrid;
    }

    public function testStopMethod()
    {
        $response = $this->datagrid->stop();
        $this->assertEquals($response, 'Stop');
    }

}
```